# Attribute for waitcursor

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, dependency-injection, ninject, custom-attributes

I'm building an application that will have many forms and there will sometimes be wait times for several situations. These wait times might be a few sec usually but according to the usability best practices it is very important to keep the user informed of what is going on and thus when he has to wait a second or more it makes the customer happy to know the application is working on the customer/ users action.

So I got interested in attributes. I want an attribute that I can apply to several methods all over my gui where I want.
I do not want to write

> this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
>
> ...do something...
>
> this.Cursor = Cursors.DefaultCursor;

in all my methods. It's also against best practice to write something more than once.

So... if someone can help me with an attribute that sets
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; when a method is invoked
and when the method ends the attribute does this.Cursor = Cursors.DefaultCursor; I'd be very happy!

Comment: Why dependency-injection tag ?

Answer (score 2):

Have A look at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.interception You can define an attribute and interceptor that changes the cursor before and after the method call.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could follow a `using` type pattern for your WaitCursor usage?

Try http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/WaitCursor.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/waitcursor.aspx?q=using+waitcursor

```
using (new StWaitCursor())
{ 
    // .. do some work while WaitCursor is enabled .. 
}
```

This only really works when you have discreet and non-nested procedures. The first example supports stack unwinding so you can potentially nest the using blocks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That should work well even for nested procedures if `StWaitCursor` stores the current cursor before switching to wait cursor, and then restore the previous cursor rather than just set `Default`.

Comment: Thanks but I can not see how you'd turn that into an attribute you can apply to the methods you want it on.